# How to define fonts in prefix.pch for multiple languages in xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

In my application i have define the font families in **prefix.pch** file. All of them are English fonts. Now i have localized the app to support Other language. So, my question is how can i define the fonts based on the selected language (phone language)

```
#define FONT_H1 [UIFont fontWithName:@"Roboto-Medium" size:18.0]
#define FONT_H2 [UIFont fontWithName:@"Roboto-Light" size:16.0]
#define FONT_H3 [UIFont fontWithName:@"Oswald" size:14.0f]
#define FONT_H4 [UIFont fontWithName:@"Roboto-Light" size:14.0]
```

Comment: You can create constants.h and add in that

Comment: Can't i use prefix.pch?

Comment: I guess we can't use .pch for fonts.

Comment: Currently i have defined in .pch, it's working fine. But I don't know how the define those based on the selected language

Comment: you can use localisations !

Answer (score 0):

You need to write somewhere in your .m file i think

like

```
if([[[NSLocale preferredLanguages] objectAtIndex:0] isEqualToString:@"en-US"]) {
//font for english

}
else {
//Font for chinese

}
```